# how to change the css of default select2 placeholder color?

Tags: jquery, css

I am using select2 plugin. In the mandatory fields I have to give the select2 placeholder color as red.

How do I change the default select2 placeholder color to red?

**HTML**

```
<select id="leadadd_mode_of_enq" name="leadadd_mode_of_enq" class="select2 req_place" data-select-search="true" placeholder="Mode of enquiry">
    <option value="1">Opt1</option>
    <option value="2">Opt2</option>
</select>
```

**CSS**

```
.req_place::-webkit-select-placeholder{
    color:#FFF !important;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I understand what you want correctly, you probably want to use this selector.

Original CSS which make the placeholder gray

```
.select2-default {
  color: #f00 !important;
}
```

Change your preferred placeholder color

```
.select2-default {
  color: #f00 !important;
}
```

Specific placeholder color (using id)

```
#s2id_<elementid> .select2-default {
  color: #f00 !important;
}
```

Replace  with the original `input` or `select` id

In this case

```
#s2id_leadadd_mode_of_enq .select2-default {
  color: #f00 !important;
}
```

Also, another note for placeholder to work, you have to add an empty `<option></option>` or else the first option will be automatically selected, but not the placeholder.

Like so

```
<select id="leadadd_mode_of_enq" name="leadadd_mode_of_enq" class="select2 req_place" data-select-search="true" placeholder="Mode of enquiry">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">Opt1</option>
  <option value="2">Opt2</option>
</select>
```

[See Demo](http://codepen.io/josephting/pen/LsDbG)

Comment: I'm using version 4.0.3 and I had to change `.select2-selection__placeholder` because the `select2-default` class doesn't exist.

Answer (score 8):

the answers given are old and you can now use the css class

```
.select2-selection__placeholder {
    color: #FF0000;
}
```

Comment: That's nice, but you must add the `!important` property in order to work.

Comment: @Brhaka you should be including the select2 css before you add in your own ( you should do this as normal practice to avoid 3rd parties overwriting any styling in your project.) this way any of your customisations overwrite the defaults without the requirement of !important.

Comment: Sure, that’s a good practice! But if you’re using inline or internal CSS, the `!important` property come in handy!

Answer (score 3):

select2 copies css classes from source `select` tag to it's container. So, you can simply use this css for your html:

```
.select2-container.req_place .select2-default .select2-chosen { 
    color:#FFF !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this default css instead

```
  ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
    color: pink;
  }

  ::-moz-placeholder {
    /* Firefox 19+ */
    color: pink;
  }

  :-ms-input-placeholder {
    /* IE 10+ */
    color: pink;
  }

  :-moz-placeholder {
    /* Firefox 18- */
    color: pink;
  }
```